# Order of Subscriptions == Order of Observations for single-threaded Subjects?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

When I subscribe multiple observers to a subject, 
is there a guarantee that the observers are called in the order they were subscribed?

A simple test in Linqpad seems to imply YES:

```cs
var observable = Observable.Return("foo");
var subject    = new Subject<string>();

subject.Subscribe(_=>"Observer 1".Dump());
subject.Subscribe(_=>"Observer 2".Dump());
subject.Subscribe(_=>"Observer 3".Dump());

observable.Subscribe(subject);

// Observer 1
// Observer 2
// Observer 3
```

I understand, that in multi-threaded scenarios things can get fairly tricky, so I'd like to ask for the single-threaded case in particular. The subject is subscribed to and observed on the same thread.

Comment: This is something that you absolutely should *not* be relying on, regardless of whether it's behavior that you can confirm or not.  If you want one subscriber to always run after the other then have one of the subscribers directly call another, fire an event, or otherwise perform an action that will cause the subsequent subscribers to run.

Comment: Related: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac721f91-4dbc-40b8-a2b2-19f00998239f/order-of-subscriptions-order-of-observations?forum=rx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I subscribe multiple observers to a subject, is there a guarantee that the observers are called in the order they were subscribed?

No, this is an implementation detail that happens to be true at the moment.